# what is causing "Port 443 is already being handled; removing" error in the Tor debug.log?

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi

After following the [Tor Bridge installation docs](https://community.torproject.org/relay/setup/bridge/debian-ubuntu/) and the [download instructions for Ubuntu](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en#ubuntu), I've successfully confirmed connection to the Tor network via a Raspberry Pi 2 with Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver; although I'm connected as confirmed by the **notices.log**, the log-file stops after "Performing Bandwidth self-test...done", so I examined the **debug.log** file- although there is some network activity documented, it appears that the majority of traffic is being scrubbed or "washed" with repeating output "Port 443 is already being handled; removing" (as detailed in the below snapshot).

[image]

Although the Tor docs apparently recommend punching holes for 80 and 443, those ports are already in-use on my network, so I set `ORPort` to 3443 within the **torrc**-config file, which includes the following parameters within the below markdown (please feel free to review my [blog-post](https://www.alexanderjsingleton.com/how-to-set-up-a-tor-bridge-with-a-raspberry-pi-using-ubuntu-server/) detailing my approach if need be):

```
BridgeRelay1
ORPort 3443
ServerTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/bin/obfs4proxy.
ServerTransportListenAddr obfs4 0.0.0.0:3448
Uncomment line ExtORPort auto.
Nickname choose-whatever-you-want
ContactInfo your-contact-name <your-email-address@whatever.com>
```

Can someone please confirm if the "Port 443 is already being handled; removing" is an error due to my configuration file or if this is normal under the circumstances (ie unable to utilize 443 due to existing network preferences)?  How can I resolve?  I'd sincerely appreciate it- thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After repeating the [TorProject install](https://community.torproject.org/relay/setup/bridge/debian-ubuntu/) on another Raspberry Pi 3, I discovered that I incorrectly transcribed the gpg-keys while adding the repository for the Debian/Ubuntu install as listed within their docs (I recommend folks install Xubuntu to access the Xubuntu Desktop broswer/FireFox so you can accurately copy/paste [those keys](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en#ubuntu) instead of risking error transcribing by typo on the keyboard).  If running a Tor Bridge, I'd also recommend setting your Raspberry Pi 2/3/B+ torrc config-files according to the parameters specified within the below markdown:

```
RunAsDaemon 1

Log notice file /var/log/tor/notices.log
Log debug file /var/log/tor/debug.log

ORPort 3443

ServerTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/bin/obfs4proxy
ServerTransportListenAddr obfs4 0.0.0.0:3448

ExtORPort auto

Nickname your-nickname
EmailAddress <your-email-address>

ExitPolicy reject *:*
```

After monitoring the Tor Bridge console files and periodically checking Tor Atlas, I was finally able to [confirm success](https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#details/67D4FADB0D78F40CFF069FBF271678CECAC28AB4) about 4.5 hours later and no longer observed the "Port 443 is already being handled; removing" flag within the debug.log file- hope that helps!